# How do I make a customized type array of customized type elements in Go?

Tags: arrays, go

I'm attempting to create a person with a name and salary, then an array of persons. The error I get at "data[0] = a" states: "cannot use a (type person) as type *person in assignment." Is there some sort of casting I need to do, as in Java?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
    name   string
    salary float64
}

type people []*person

func main() {

    var data = make(people, 10)

    var a person
    var b person
    a.name = "John Smith"
    a.salary = 74000
    b.name = "Jane Smith"
    b.salary = 82000

    data[0] = a
    data[1] = b

    fmt.Print(data)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You construct slice of *pointers* to `person`. That's why you should take pointer of you `a` and `b`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
    name   string
    salary float64
}

type people []*person

func main() {
    var data = make(people, 10)

    var a person
    var b person
    a.name = "John Smith"
    a.salary = 74000
    b.name = "Jane Smith"
    b.salary = 82000

    data[0] = &a
    data[1] = &b

    fmt.Print(data)
}
```

Alternative approach is to define `a` and `b` as pointers to structs.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
    name   string
    salary float64
}

type people []*person

func main() {
    var data = make(people, 10)
    a := &person{}
    b := &person{}

    a.name = "John Smith"
    a.salary = 74000
    b.name = "Jane Smith"
    b.salary = 82000

    data[0] = a
    data[1] = b

    fmt.Print(data)
}
```

Comment: Or just `data[0] = &person{"John Smith", 74000}`

Comment: `data := people{{"John Smith", 74000}, {"Jane Smith", 82000}}`